# Can anyone tell me how to make my these images have a hover?

Tags: html, css

I am building a site in HTML & CSS and I have a section where I would like to have my images change when hovered over. My problem is I can get the first one to do what I want, but when I try the same method on the images that are side by side, everything gets moved or it just doesn't work. You can see the example of the first hexagon that changes in the "Core Values" section of the site. You can either pull my Githib repo [here](https://github.com/jshuadvd/JoshuaDavid-HTML-CSS-Site) or I have also added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7k50bhva/3/) . Thank you!

```css
.hex-image  {
 padding-top: 70px;
}


.hexy-hex {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 60px;
 height: 900px; 
}
 
.hexy-hex-2 {
 position: relative;
 top: -45px; 
}

.hexy-hex-3 {
 position: relative;
 top: -45px; 
}

.hexy-hex-4 {
 position: relative;
 top: -45px; 
}

.hexy-hex-5 {
 position: relative;
 top: -45px; 
} 

.lt-blue-hex {
 margin: 0px;    
}


.drk-grey-hex {
 margin: 0px;  
}

.lt-grey-hex {
 margin: 0px;   
}

#Spirituality {
 background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/DPTzosk.png');
 height: 200px;
 width: 175px;
}

#Spirituality:hover {
 background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Ha9YgEG.png');
}
```

```html
    <section class="hex-image">  
        
        <h1 style="color: #686868" align="center">Core Values</h1>
        
        
         <div class="hexy-hex" align="center"> 
                   
          <div id="Spirituality"></div>   
          <!-- <a class="lt-blue-hex cv" href="http://"><img src="images/blue-hex-up-sm.png" title="JDI" /></a> -->
          
                   
         
         <div class="hexy-hex-2" align="center">
                   
          <div id="Honesty"></div>
          
          <div id="Innovation"></div>
           
           
          
          
           <a class="drk-grey-hex" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/n87uvmk.png" title="JDI" /></a>
           
           <a class="lt-grey-hex" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vCNrceH.png" title="JDI" /></a> 
                   
         
         <div class="hexy-hex-3" align="center">
              
           <a class="lt-grey-hex" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vCNrceH.png" title="JDI" /></a>
           
           <a class="lt-blue-hex" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DPTzosk.png" title="JDI" /></a> 
                
           <a class="drk-grey-hex" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/n87uvmk.png" title="JDI" /></a>
    
           
        
         <div class="hexy-hex-4" align="center" >
              
           <a class="lt-blue-hex-2" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DPTzosk.png" title="JDI" /></a>
           
           <a class="drk-grey-hex-2" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/n87uvmk.png" title="JDI" /></a>                
           <a class="lt-grey-hex-2" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vCNrceH.png" title="JDI" /></a>
           
           <a class="lt-blue-hex-2" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DPTzosk.png" title="JDI" /></a>
         
         
         <div class="hexy-hex-5" align="center" >
          
           <a class="drk-grey-hex-2" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/n87uvmk.png" title="JDI" /></a>
                 
           <a class="lt-grey-hex-2" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vCNrceH.png" title="JDI" /></a>
                  
           <a class="lt-blue-hex-2" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DPTzosk.png" title="JDI" /></a>
               
           <a class="drk-grey-hex-2" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/n87uvmk.png" title="JDI" /></a>
          
           <a class="lt-grey-hex-2" href="http://"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vCNrceH.png" title="JDI" /></a>
    
         </div>
        </div>
       </div> 
      </div>
     </div> 
       
     <div class="clear"></div> 
        
</section>
```

Comment: You should only post the code which is relevant to your problem and if needed abstract everything away which makes it harder for us to reproduce the problem (ie things like `images/dark-grey-hex-up-sm.png` which we cannot load without loading your full repo). Ideally in such a case provide a fiddle or similar.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with your html, css and js because as Jey mentioned, posting all your codes here makes it hard for us to pin-point the solution for your issue(s) and problem(s).

Comment: Sorry @JeyDWork here you are: https://jsfiddle.net/7k50bhva/4/

Comment: @AndrewLyndem https://jsfiddle.net/7k50bhva/4/

Comment: Where is this "Core Values" section on your fiddle? Try to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then we will be able to help you better.

Comment: There's an awful lot of stray closing div tags all over your html. Let me just clean that up for you and then see what your issue is

Comment: @dave I have edited the post so you can see the pertinent code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So onto your problem: It seems what you try to achieve is a mouseover effect like on the first hexagon. It further seems you already tried it a failed because the hexagons (`<div>`s) did get displayed over each other. Instead you builded your hexagon pyramid with `<a>`-tags but now there is no mouseover effect because the `<a>`-tags have hard coded `<img>`s which cannot be changed with CSS.

Like in all cases you have several possibilities. One could be to change the `<img>`s on mouseover via JavaScript/jQuery. Another (out of even more) would be to try an approach via CSS and as you already tried that yourself (at least from the comments in your code it looks that way), lets go with that.

So your `<div>`s in the second row get displayed over each other because by default a `<div>` is a block element. If you want them to stack up just like your `<a>`-tags from which you built the pyramid now you need them to behave like inline elements (because thats what `<a>`-tags are). This can be done (for example) by adding the following CSS rule to your `<div>`s in question:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Now you can use them just like `<a>`s and so set the initial background image via CSS and change it as well via CSS and `:hover` selectors. I've updated your fiddle and have done that for the second line (obviously not with the images you intended but it should be understandable): https://jsfiddle.net/7k50bhva/5/
You can follow that example for the other lines.

Note that if you want to have real links I would place transparent `<a>`-tags within the `<div>`s. On those transparent (so contentless) `<a>`-tags you will have to specify `width` and `height`.